# How to find row number of a chosen number in a triangular number sequence?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to find the row number in a chosen square in this:

[image]

For instance if I choose `getRow(17)` I would get `answer = 6`. I don't even know where to begin. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
class RowShelf{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      getRow(24); // ans = 7
      getRow(17); // ans = 6
   }

   public static int getRow(int sq){

  }
}
```

Comment: How are you modelling the table? What kind of a data-structure is being used to hold that table? Only then you would be able to move forward which how you can iterate through the table to find a row for a symbol.

Comment: How can I help you? Would you like to receive some suggestions or  do you prefer to see the final code?  Where the number are contained? Are they contained in a matrix?

Comment: @acornagl please don't write code for people and hand it out, that is not the way to learn and certainly not the purpose of this website.

Comment: Where to begin: think of a number that is outside of the drawing you have. Like 117 or 232. Now try to calculate manually, with pen, paper and pocket calculator, which row it will be in. Pay attention to how you are doing it, and try to transform the operations you are doing to operations that a computer will do.

Comment: The way I solved it, is think of it this way. In row 1, you have 1 number. In row 2, you have 2 numbers. This continues in this pattern. In order to solve it, keep track of the row you are currently on, and also keeping track of the maximum amount of numbers that can be contained in that row. Keep going in a for loop until you reach the value you pushed into the method, then return the row you are currently on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's easy, use `while-loop`.

```
public static int getRow(int number) {
    int result=0;
    int sum=0;  
    while(sum<number) {
        result++;
        sum+=result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

With every iteration you add to `sum` variable one more value than the iteration before until you reach the limit set as the argument. Return the number of loops, that is the result.

Check the outputs:

```
getRow(24);      // 7
getRow(17);      // 6
getRow(1765465); // 1879
```

---

Improving @Shahid's answer gives your a more straightforward way:

```
public static int getRow(int number) {
    return (int) Math.ceil((Math.sqrt(8*number+1)-1) / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For triangular number n, where r is row number:

```
n = r(r+1) / 2
=> r^2 + r - 2n = 0
```

The direct mathematical expression would be:

```
r = (sqrt(8n+1)-1) / 2
```

Do the coding for this.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the pattern. In the principal diagonal you can see that the numbers is the sum of all numbers to a row. In other words, from your image you can see that:

```
sumDiag(1,1) = 1
sumDiag(2,2) = sumDiag(1,1) + 2
sumDiag(3,3) = sumDiag(2,2) + 3
```

This could be translated to the following:

```
sumRow(1) = 1
sumRow(2) = 1 + 2 = 3
sumRow(3) = 1 + 2 + 3 = 6

which is: (r+1)*(r)/2
```

So you need to find the upper and lower bound to know in which row is the number you want to find. This would be the optimal solution, because as you said *"the rows are infinite"*

From your code you want to find: `getRow(24)`

If you follow my hints you will notice that `sumRow(7) = 28 and` `sum(6) = 21`.

**24 is between 28 and 21, thus the row is 7**

Answer (score 0):

**round(sqrt(2*n))** 
This worked for me when I attempted to solve a UVa Online Judge problem. It worked for numbers upto 10^18.

Here is the code to output row:

```
long long getRow( long long n ){
    double row = round(sqrt(2*n));
    return (long long)row;
}
```